Huawei old model U9200 factory reset problem
I want to reset my Huawei Ascend P1 XL U9200E because I forgot my password, but USB debugging is not enabled and my volume-up button is not working.
How can I go to recovery mode, or do you know any other method to go to fastboot or recovery mode?
